# Spring 3.0 forwarding request to different controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

What is the proper way to forward a request in spring to a different controller?

```
@RequestMapping({"/someurl"})
public ModelAndView execute(Model model) {
    if (someCondition) {
        //forward to controller A
    } else {
        //forward to controller B
    }
}
```

All of the controller have dependencies injected by Spring, so I can't just create them and call them myself, but I want the request attributes to be passed on to the other controllers.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try returning a String instead, and the String being the forward url.

```
@RequestMapping({"/someurl"})
public String execute(Model model) {
    if (someCondition) {
        return "forward:/someUrlA";
    } else {
        return "forward:/someUrlB";
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's a link to the docs for Spring 3.0.x for RedirectView, which also covers :forward. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-redirecting

Comment: Is it possible to do that without hardcoding "someUrlA" ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use view name like "redirect:controllerName" or "forward:controllerName". The latter will reroute request to another controller and former will tell browser to redirect request to another url.

docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring `RedirectView` to dispatch request from one controller to other controller.
It will be by default Request type "GET"

```
RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/controllerRequestMapping/methodmapping.do", true);
```

Comment: Redirect is not forward. redirect sends headers with redirect command to client and client just follow location, forward just delegate request handling to other handler within same request.